# What is the most effective design for numerous classes with similar, but no congruent constructors?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm working with a library of classes which have, first of all, *enormous* constructors, with fifteen or twenty arguments passed. There are twenty or so of these classes, and they have similar but not precisely the same arguments. In some, argument twelve is omitted, in others, it's specified but not required...

I'm thinking of composing these arguments into objects because many of them are related to each other, e.g., FirstName, LastName and Email Address into a Person object. But this seems to lead to a couple of monster classes, whereby NO use of the object ever uses ALL of the arguments, and most uses will use only a few.

Right now all of the validation logic is in all of the constructors...if I can crack the problem of chaining the constructors well down the inheritance chain, then I can create an abstract Validate() method that each class can override, and simplify the design. I checked Refactoring to Patterns, but I didn't see anything that seemed to bear directly on this question.

Note: this is not a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568459/a-good-design-pattern-for-almost-similar-objects) - I'm talking about similar constructors, not similar objects. I've got abstract base classes out the wazoo.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm thinking of composing these arguments into objects because many of them are related to each other

That sounds like a good step to me.

> But this seems to lead to a couple of monster classes

I don't see why they need to be "monster" classes at all - you can keep them as simple DTO classes, although you'd probably want to provide some validation that if an email address is specified, it really *is* a valid email address, etc.

> whereby NO use of the object ever uses ALL of the arguments

Well, no use of the object ever uses all of the *properties*. That's okay - few uses of `DateTime` use every single property, for example.

You don't have to specify all the values when you construct a `Person` - work out which ones are truly required for *all* uses, and put them in the constructor... then either use *optional parameters* for the parameter, or just properties to make the `Person` type mutable. So you could have:

```
Person person = new Person("Jon", "Skeet", // Required parameters
                           email: "skeet@pobox.com"); // Optional
```

Or:

```
Person person = new Person("Jon", "Skeet") { Email = "skeet@pobox.com" };
```

Personally I like the first approach as it means your object can be immutable, but it depends on how you feel about optional parameters.

Either way, your other classes now just need to take these bigger blobs (e.g. two `Person` references and a `Location` reference, instead of 12 different references). They can assume that all the *required* values in the bigger blobs are already populated (as they'll be validated in the constructor) and then they can just check that any optional ones that they happen to require are also filled in.